# Docker-compose check latest version of an image

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is there a way to check if docker-compose is running the latest version of an image? I know that I can run docker-compose pull to get the latest version, but what happens if I run the pull command and docker-compose already has the newest image? Does the pull request count against my Docker Hub pull request limit?

My end goal is to check for a new image every 24 hours without using Watchtower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a docker pull against the ":latest" tag of an image, docker will only pull that image if this version of the image is not on your local repository/computer. Works lit `git pull`, basically. Docker-compose does a simple, classic docker pull, so same mechanic.

You can find a way to find your docker pull limit rate, and your number of remaining pulls in [at this link](https://www.docker.com/blog/checking-your-current-docker-pull-rate-limits-and-status/)

You can try consulting your remaining pulls, then lauching `docker pull <some image>:latest`, consulting your remaining pulls again *(it'll show the same -1)* and doing the same pull again. Pull checks the image version, does not detect changes, does not pull, your remaining pulls number stay the same.

Anyway, you get 100 pulls/6 hours if you are an anonymous user and 200 pulls/6 hours if you are an authentified user. For your use case, you would be okay even if you were pulling the image every day.

Comment: Thanks that answers my question